Unable to run a for loop with Findstr in a batch script
I have below batch script, which basically looks for CurrMonth in the file and set the the third token to the month
when i do findstr /c:"CurrMonth" %SPOOL_FILE% , it get the result as below
Server    CurrMonth    Apr

but below batch script is not giving me the value of month as Apr
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SPOOL_FILE=E:\EPM\output.txt


FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3 skip=1" %%a ('findstr /c:"CurrMonth" %SPOOL_FILE%') DO SET Month=%%a
    
echo %Month%

endlocal


Why are you using usebackq for? that is usually used if you want to specify a file or path with spaces in it so you can use quotes but not the case here you use a comand which should be specified with back quotes "`" since you used the usebackq option. Also why you use skip=1 if the for ignores empty lines?

Why not build this in PowerShell? That is much easier.

@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_SPOOL_FILE=E:\EPM\output.txt"

for /f tokens^=3 %%G in =;('
     findstr /c:"CurrMonth" ^<"%_SPOOL_FILE%"
   ');= do set "_Month=%%~G"
    
echo/%_Month%

endlocal



When using usebackq, the correct option would be to replace ' with `
For /F "usebackq ...." %%a (` your loop cmd`) do ...




Your command below returns one line (skipped in loop):
"when i do findstr /c:"CurrMonth" %SPOOL_FILE% , it get the result as below"
Server    CurrMonth    Apr

Even when correcting what was pointed out above about usebackq, notice that your command returns one line, but when using the skip=1 option in the for /f "...skip=1" loop, you are skipping the only output line that is of interest to you...


Some further reading:

Set /?

For /?

For /F /?

Findstr /?

Commands Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, etc.


An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com


